# Conic sections and polynomials over C

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, symmetric-matrices

Let K be a field with $char(K) \neq 2$. Every polynomial $f \in K[X,Y] $ has a unique representation
$$ a_{11}x^2+a_{22}y^2+2a_{12}xy+ 2a_{13}x + 2a_{23}y + a_{33}$$

that can be identified by a matrix
$$ A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
A is symetric, so there is $ T \in GL_3(K) $ so that $T^TAT = diag(c_1,c_2,c_3)$.
The related quadratic form $ F=(x,y,z)A(x,y,z)^T $ then  equals 
$$ c_1x^2+c_2y^2+c_3z^2 $$
**Since K is algebraically closed, we can suppose that $c_i = 0$ or $c_i = 1$.**

How does that work? I don't see how a zero in every polynomial leeds to this conclusion.

To be fair, the author states that we can only relate this to our polynomial  f if we chose z = 1, but as far as I understand the argument above still holds.

Comment: Put $x'=\sqrt{c_1}x$, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Jan-Magnus Økland:
X,Y and Z can be substituted by $ x'= \sqrt{c_1}X $ and so on.
We get $K[X,Y,Z] \cong K[x',y',z']$.
Since K is algebraically closed, we can do this with arbitrary constants $c_i \in K$.